# Angular.js: directive object in scope is always undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

***EDIT:** Forked @EliteOctagon's plunker and oddly it's working! Can't understand why the code below isn't. [http://plnkr.co/edit/y8uvulA9RHQ1Y9mwzin1](http://plnkr.co/edit/y8uvulA9RHQ1Y9mwzin1_)*

***EDIT2:** Forked the previous plunker and added a $timeout to controller's logic and it stopped working! Guess it's really loading order. Check it out: [http://plnkr.co/edit/ivmGQmEHTatNzBWhppyf](http://plnkr.co/edit/ivmGQmEHTatNzBWhppyf_)*

I'm new to angular and can't get my head wrapped around directive isolate scopes.

I need to create a directive to print out a `<span/>` in my page with info regarding and object in the view controller.

What I was trying to do is isolate the directive scope and pass the object through an attribute with two-way binding (see code below). However, when trying to access the object in the `link` function of the directive it always comes out as undefined.

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance guys.

**Directive use in html view template:**

`<party-starts party="party"></party-starts>`

**Directive JS code**

```
.directive('partyStarts', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div id="partyStart><i class="icon ion-pin"></i> </div>',
        scope: {
            party: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, el) {
            var party = scope.party;
            var icon = el.find('i');
            var statusStr = angular.element('<span/>');
            var final;

            console.log('scope '+scope);

            if(party.Diatodo){
                if(party.datahora.isSame(moment(), 'day') || party.datahora.isSame(moment().add(1, 'd'), 'day')){
                    icon.css({
                        'color': 'green'            
                    });
                    statusStr.text(' É hoje');
                    el.append(statusStr);
                }else{
                    icon.css({
                        'color': '#999'            
                    });
                    statusStr.text(' Começa em '+party.datahora.fromNow());
                    el.append(statusStr);
                }
                return;
            }

            if(party.datahora.unix() == party.datahoraf.unix()){
                final = party.datahora.clone().add(1, 'd').hour(6);
            }else{
                final = party.datahoraf;
            }

            if(party.datahora.twix(final).isCurrent()){
                icon.css({
                    'color': 'green'            
                });
                statusStr.text(' Começou há '+party.datahora.fromNow());
                el.append(statusStr);
            }else if(party.datahora.twix(final).isFuture()){
                icon.css({
                    'color': '#999'            
                });
                statusStr.text(' Começa em '+party.datahora.fromNow());
                el.append(statusStr);
            }else{
                icon.css({
                    'color': 'red'            
                });
                statusStr.text(' Já terminou');
                el.append(statusStr);
            }
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: can you put up a plunker with some code? here is a blank template http://plnkr.co/edit/TkONdJqtD6nSg6s0Da59

Comment: As long as $scope.parent is defined inside the parent controller, there should be no issue. Are you possibly using party-starts in an ng-if or ng-repeat, and therefore unintentially creating a new child scope?

Comment: no ng-repeat loops here, just a regular object in the controller scope being passed

Comment: What does the parent controller look like with $scope.party?

Comment: @EliteOctagon just forked your plunker with equivalent code and it just works... Can't understand it at all :( http://plnkr.co/edit/y8uvulA9RHQ1Y9mwzin1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the directive's party scope variable in a watcher and wait for it to be initialized. In your case you don't do this and so all your logic is being run before scope.party is assigned.

```
link: function(scope, el) {

  var watcher = scope.$watch('party', function() {
    if(scope.party === undefined) return;

    // at this point it is defined, do work

    // delete watcher if appropriate
    watcher();
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess you're right. Because I've wrapped the other plunker in a timeout and it stops working. http://plnkr.co/edit/ivmGQmEHTatNzBWhppyf

Comment: $timeout could make it work if the timeout was long enough, but use a $watch instead of a $timeout, because you can't define time.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you very much see updated plunker in EDIT2

Comment: I was just wrapping the controller logic in $timeout to test for your hypothesis, not to solve the problem, for that I used $watch as you suggested! :)

Comment: @wbeange why are you wrapping $watch with custom function and calling itself repeatedly? Isn't $watch already doing it anyway?

Comment: @ruuter we are waiting for the scope variable to get initialized

Comment: @wbeange hmm, but isn't it already initialized in directive `scope: { party: '=' }`. Empty or not, it should be initialized and automatically updated by $watch itself. Not sure if I'm missing something here. It works without extra wrapper function for me. Even when party is not initialized outside directive, before $resource returns.

Comment: @ruuter it may or may not be initialized - this watch waits for it to be initialized

Answer (score 9):

I don't think this is an issue with load order. From what I can tell the code you provided should function. Here is a plunker with a working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Bsn3Vyjrmb311b8ykzU1 There is also logging to the console, which verifies that `scope.party` is initialized with the correct value on load.

Click on the live preview (the Eye Icon on the right sidebar) to view the example.

Also, here is a diagram that showed up in my twitter feed the other day that I found very useful for explaining isolate scope in an understandable way. Hope this helps :-)

[image]

Comment: Awesome infographic, really useful! Thanks! :D Can't vote up (not enough rep) but I'll leave it here `+1` :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason why it was undefined was because the timing was incorrect. Say you have a directive that shows a list of products:

```
<my-products products='httpLoadedProducts'>/<my-products>
```

And you define it like so:

```
.directive('myProducts', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      products: '=',
    },
    templateUrl: 'directives/products-template.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       console.log(scope.products);
    }
  }
})
```

If the list of products comes from an HTTP request, it is very likely that the directive will be instantatied *before* the products are loaded, therefore the `console.log` prints `undefined`.

One solution is to instantiate the directive *after* the items are loaded. This will ensure that the `link` function runs after the items are loaded.

So, either wrap the directive with an `ng-if`, like this:

```
<div ng-if='httpLoadedProducts'>
   <my-products products='httpLoadedProducts'>/<my-products>
</div>
```

Or use wbeange's answer to watch the model for changes.